# An Audio Equivalent for 'Optically'

Tags: synonyms, dialectal-equivalent

I was recently involved in a discussion on headphones, and realized I came short on a word for 'Audio' that could be used in the same way the word 'optically' is used for 'Optics'.

For example, I could say, "Lens A is optically superior to Lens B".

Is there such an equivalent word for 'audio'?

Comment: This is something to look up for yourself.  In fact, ‘aurally’ is often used (aures is Latin for ears).

Comment: I think "aurally" corresponds to "visually", not to "optically".

Comment: @GEdgar since both of those mean "with the eyes", not sure what you're trying to say ;o) ...

Comment: "fidelity" is a word used with audio speaker quality I believe .. it is also used with "video fidelity"  "headphones 'A' are higher fidelity than headphones 'B'"

Comment: ***Otically***. I had a nice answer written up, but alas ...

Answer (score 1):

"Music A is aurally superior to Music B".

**aural**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/aural)

> Of, relating to, or perceived by the ear.

Answer (score 1):

Headphone A is ***sonically*** superior to headphone B.

> [***sonic***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sonic): utilizing, produced by, or relating to sound waves sonic altimeter; broadly : of or involving sound sonic pollution

A quote from [*Popular Mechanics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HOQDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=sonic+superiority&source=bl&ots=tzL4hMsQVM&sig=uxKx4nW2roQibk0x4zeJvcQAE20&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF9tKP57raAhXvw1kKHc1pAQgQ6AEwG3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=sonic%20superiority&f=false)

> [...] the analog record player will be joining the mothball fleet of museum artifacts, made obsolete after 100 years of service by the **sonic superiority** of the digital audio compact disc.

Comment: ... How wrong they were... :-)